# The second derivative of g(t)= f(x(t), y(t))

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

For the chain rule for differentiating a function $g(t) = (f(x), y(t))$
how do you get from

the identity $g'(t) = \frac{df}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+ \frac{df}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$
to the identitiy for the double derivative

$$d''(t) = \left(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx2}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{d^{2}f}{dx\,dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}
+ \frac{df}{dx}\cdot\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}+ \left(\frac{d^2 f}{dy\,dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}
+ \frac{d^2 f}{dy^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\cdot\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{df}{dy}\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}$$

I understand how we derive $g'(t)$ but not $g''(t)$ I have tried using chain rule again  but to no avail.

Comment: I've cleaned up your MathJax usage quite a bit.  But notice that I haven't written $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y}$.  It is possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$

then:

$\frac{d^{2}g}{dt^{2}}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dg}{dt})=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt})=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}+\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}$

Now apply chain rule twice.